# How do I pipe into the 'convert' command?

Tags: bash, batch-processing, imagemagick-convert

Using Ubuntu 22.04.  I have a Bash command that produces a list of GIF files

```
$ <command>
file1.gif
file3.gif
file12.gif
...
```

I would like to convert the files in this output to PNG files using the ImageMagick `convert` command.  For a single file, the command would look something like

```
convert "<basename>.gif" "<basename>.png"
```

Since I have many files, though, I want to pipe the output of the original command into the `convert` command, like

```
$ <command> | convert "<???>" "[<???>%.gif].png"
```

where I'm attempting to use Bash's features for removing the `.gif` extension from input files and adding the `.png` extension.

Ideally, I could capture the output of each line of `<command>` as a variable and reference that variable in the `convert` portion of the command, like

```
$ <command> | convert "$1" "[$1%.gif].png"
```

where `$1` stands in for `file1.gif`, `file3.gif`, `file12.gif`, etc.  I've been searching for hours, and I can't find anything similar to that ability, though.

This is a specific example of a general Bash problem of how to pipe to a command that has two inputs, which does not have an obvious solution because the "destination" of the pipe is ambiguous.  I've also searched for solutions to that general problem, but fruitlessly.

Can this "one -> multiple" piping be done from the command line?

Comment: You want a loop, not a pipe. Pipes change a program's stdin source to come from something else's stdout. That's not what you need to do here.

Comment: (Pipes notably/emphatically _don't_ provide command-line arguments in and of themselves -- you need to use something in your pipeline that does the work of taking content off stdin and putting that content on something else's command line if that's a thing you want done; for simple cases the common tool is xargs, though it has some serious caveats and needs to be used carefully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick as follows as an example. I have two images lena.jpg and zelda1.jpg and I want to convert them to GIFs.

```
echo "lena.jpg zelda1.jpg" | convert @- +adjoin -set filename:f "%t" "%[filename:f].gif"
```

The @- takes a list from stdin which in this case is just an echo of the file names.  The +adjoin is needed to avoid having the image go into different frames of the GIF. (Remove the +adjoin if you want to make and animated GIF). With the +adjoin, you get one output per input. The -set filename:f stores the names from %t which excludes the suffix. They are then recalled in the output as %[filename:f].  Change f to anything you want or just keep f.

Note: the @- may need you to modify your policy.xml file to be able to use @.

Answer (score 2):

Not at a computer to test until tomorrow, but the **ImageMagick** suite can read its input filenames from a file preceded by `@`, so if `filelist.txt` contains 2 filenames, you can append the images side-by-side using:

```
convert @filelist.txt +append output.png
```

If you want to read filenames from **ImageMagick**'s stdin, you can use:

```
printf "%s\n" file1.png file2.png | convert @- +append output.png
```

But you want multiple output files, so you want `mogrify`, so you need:

```
xargs ... | magick mogrify -format PNG @-
```

---

Or... completely different concept... you can get them all done in parallel with **GNU Parallel** and let it strip the GIF extension and replace it with PNG:

```
xargs ... | parallel magick {} {.}.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop, using a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to avoid the bugs described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- this code uses bash extensions and is not sh-compatible

yourcommand() {
  printf '%s\n' file1.gif file3.gif etc.gif
}

while IFS= read -r infile; do
  convert "$infile" "${infile%.*}.png"
done < <(yourcommand)
```

If you care more about portability than the bugs described behind the link, then you can pipe to the loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

yourcommand | while IFS= read -r infile; do
  convert "$infile" "${infile%.*}.png"
done
```

Comment: Never knows if _parameter expansions_ are posixly valid

Comment: @GillesQuénot, some are, some aren't. `${var%pattern}` is one of the ones that is -- search for "remove smallest suffix pattern" in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02